# IWindowSession.java NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.flags' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, null, crash, fatal-error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.flags' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1972)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:836)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:926)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:390)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:525)
at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

showing some fatal exception in IWindowSession.java line 836
android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay  please help to resolve it.